# How to split a string on * and - in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

Inorder to split the string i have used the following code.

```
$string = "-sev*yes-sev1*no-sev2*yes";
split('[-*]', $string).
```

As split is deprecated, can you please suggest an alternative to split the string into an array. I have tried with explode, but it is not serving my purpose.
The output should look like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => sev
    [1] => yes
    [2] =>  sev1
    [3] =>  no
    [4] =>  sev2
    [5] =>  yes
)
```

Thank u all for ur responses..I tried `preg_split('[-*]', $string)`. It has split has the string character wise. I have modified it to `preg_split('/[-*]/', $string)`. It is working well. It would be great if you can explain me the difference.

Comment: Show some output you want to achieve, i mean sample output array

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your latest doubt on `preg_split`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**preg_split**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) as:

```
$string = "-sev*yes-sev1*no-sev2*yes";
$array = preg_split('/-|\*/', $string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

or

```
$array = preg_split('/-|\*/', $string);
```

alternatively you can also use [**strtok**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
$tok = strtok($string, "-*");
$array = array();
while ($tok !== false) {
    $array[] = $tok;
    $tok = strtok("-*");
}
```

**EDIT:**

In

```
 preg_split('[-*]', $string);
```

the `[ ]` are treated as delimiters and not as char class hence you are using the regex `-*` for splitting which means zero or more hyphens.

but in

```
preg_split('/[-*]/', $string);
```

you are using the regex `[-*]` which is the char class to match either `*` or a `-`

Answer (score 5):

you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: Is explode an alternative here? He needs regex to use '[-*]', eplode does not handle regexp.

Answer (score 3):

[Preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just change split to preg_split.

[preg_split() in PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two replacements for split:

- If you need to use regular expressions, use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split).
- If you do not need to use regular expressions, use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), as it is faster than `preg_split()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming your expected output is `array('sev', 'yes', 'sev1', 'no', 'sev2', 'yes')`, you can use [`preg_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$data = preg_split('/[-*]/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Or, considering that it looks like you have keyed segments (meaning that the first `yes` is bound to `sev`, the first `no` is bound to `sev1`, etc), you might be better off doing either multiple explodes:

```
$result = array();
$data = explode('-', $string);
foreach ($data as $str) {
    if (empty($str)) continue;
    list ($key, $value) = explode('*', $str);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Or converting it to a url style segment, and using [`parse_str`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)...

```
$tmp = str_replace(array('-', '*'), array('&', '='), $string);
parse_str($tmp, $result);
```

Both of these will generate arrays like:

```
array(
    'sev' => 'yes',
    'sev1' => 'no',
    'sev2' => 'yes',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split()`.

```
$string = "-sev*yes-sev1*no-sev2*yes"; 
$result = preg_split('/[-*]/', $string);
```